# C++ compiler error "no matching function"

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

These are the two functions involved:

```
int FixedLengthRecordFile :: write (const int numRec, const FixedLengthFieldsRecord & rec)
{
    /*** some code ***/

    return rec.write(file); // FILE* file is an attribute of FixedLengthRecordFile
}


int FixedLengthFieldsRecord :: write (FILE* file) { /* ... code ... */ }
```

And I get this error:

```
FixedLengthRecordFile.cpp: In member function ‘int FixedLengthRecordFile::write(int, const FixedLengthFieldsRecord&)’:
FixedLengthRecordFile.cpp:211:23: error: no matching function for call to ‘FixedLengthFieldsRecord::write(FILE*&) const’
FixedLengthRecordFile.cpp:211:23: note: candidate is:
FixedLengthFieldsRecord.h:35:7: note: int FixedLengthFieldsRecord::write(FILE*) <near match>
FixedLengthFieldsRecord.h:35:7: note:   no known conversion for implicit ‘this’ parameter from ‘const FixedLengthFieldsRecord*’ to ‘FixedLengthFieldsRecord*’
FixedLengthRecordFile.cpp:213:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

What is the cause of the error? I don't see anything wrong in the code. Besides, I've got two other similar functions (write), and it works just fine.

Comment: And also please show the declaration of the functions in the class.

Comment: Do you have prototype of `FixedLengthFieldsRecord :: write` before the implementation of `FixedLengthRecordFile :: write`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int FixedLengthRecordFile::write( const int numRec, 
                                  const FixedLengthFieldsRecord& rec)
{
   /*** some code ***/

    return rec.write(file); // FILE* file is an attribute of FixedLengthRecordFile
}


int FixedLengthFieldsRecord::write(FILE* file)
```

You pass parameters by `const` and `const` reference, however, the function `rec.write(file)` you called is not a `const` function, which may modify those passed in objects, therefore, compiler complains.

You should do the following:

```
   int FixedLengthFieldsRecord::write(FILE* file)  const  
       // add const both declaration and definition ^^^
```

Comment: However, given the function name of `write`, I wonder if this will work or not since the object `write` is called on will then be treated as const.

Comment: @user1167662 true, so OP must guarantee that it does not modify the object or do not pass by const or const ref.

Answer (score 0):

Lets look at the error message:

```
FixedLengthFieldsRecord.h:35:7:note: int FixedLengthFieldsRecord::write(FILE*)<near match>
FixedLengthFieldsRecord.h:35:7:note:   no known conversion for implicit ‘this’ parameter
    from ‘const FixedLengthFieldsRecord*’ to ‘FixedLengthFieldsRecord*’
```

It says that it cannot do a conversion from `const FixedLengthFieldsRecord*` to `FixedLengthFieldsRecord*`

That is a pretty good hint.

In the following line, `rec` is const reference,

```
return rec.write(file); // FILE* file is an attribute of FixedLengthRecordFile
```

But the following function is *NOT* `const` qualified

```
int FixedLengthFieldsRecord :: write (FILE* file) { /* ... code ... */ }
```

Hence the problem!

There are (at least) two solutions:

1) Change `rec` to a non-`const` reference

2) Change the signature of the `write()` method to be `const` qualified

Option #2 is the preferred approach.

Comment: Assuming the `write` function does not need to modify `rec` (which sort of seems unlikely considering the name?)

Comment: I understand. That is why I stated two approaches. Option #2 is preferred, but if it is not applicable. option #1 is still there.